# How to create graphical objects in Java without using any library?

Tags: java, graphics, drawing

How to create 2D graphical objects in Java without using any library?

I can not find a complete basics tutorial on creating objects in Java without using any graphics library.

Comment: You don't find those tutorials, because what you ask for is impossible. You must talk to *some* API at least, to put pixels to the screen. Java itself offers a couple of standard libraries for graphics programming, designed for cross-plattform portability you can use. But most of the time you want to use a library that gives you a binding to high performance APIs provided by the system. –– Note that, because Java is designed around the concept of a virtual machine, there's no way to talk directly to the hardware using just Java itself. It can't be done by definition.

Comment: Tell me about the APIs needed for drawing objects and how to get started with them

Comment: The operating system level: GDI and DirectX for Windows. X11 Core and XRender for Linux, *BSD, Solaris and other Unix systems. Cocoa and Quartz for MacOS X. Since the APIs mentioned so far are so different, and Java is supposed to be cross plattform, there exist no direct 1:1 bindings for them to Java. Instead there are libraries that present a uniform interface on the Java side, but use whatever the OS provides on the backend side. An API available for almost all operating systems is OpenGL for which a Java binding exists in the form of LWJGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the Java 2D API:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/

You can also have a look at the source code:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Graphics.java

Good luck!